# Unable to find the task "Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions" in TFS online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am doing CI automation for Dot net application. I had did token replacement using the task "Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions" in TFS for configuration replacement.

[image]

Now i am trying the same in the TFS online. In TFS online i am not able to find the same task(Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions).

Comment: Share `HTML` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an out of the box task, you need to install the release management utility task extension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks